# Coloring complete Row based on values from Columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to color the complete Excel row based upon the value of a cell in column.

I have three columns (`Item`, `Price` and `Status`) and want to color the row if the `Status` value is:

- DELIVERED (to Green)
- REJECTED  (to Red)
- WIP (to Orange).

Answer (score 31):

You can use (non-VBA) conditional formatting for this

If your Status column was in column C then - having selected all the rows in the area of interest - you can use rules such as this to format the entire row based on the column C entries

`=$C1="REJECTED"` and pick Red
`=$C1="WIP"` and pick Orange etc

Change your column reference to suit

The sample below is from Excel 2010

*{NB: Change your text case if necessary}*

See [Debra Dalgleish's site](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html) for more detail

[image]